# Use quotation marks after "that which is called" and similar phrases?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

> The solution is to foo, producing what is called a bar.

or

> The solution is to foo, producing what is called a "bar".

Should I use generally use one over the other; and if so, which one? If either is acceptable, then which style guides (if any) have an explicit preference?

Comment: No matter which way you do it, it seems likely to end up _foobar_.

Comment: *The guy called Called called.*  Isn't it clearer to write *The guy called "Called" called*?

Comment: Quote marks (properly used) have an important syntactic purpose.  If a word or phrase is a quotation then it's syntactic role is no longer the sum of the words contained in it.  Rather, in all the cases I can think of, the quoted text effectively becomes a noun.  Without the quotes the sentence would often have invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Putting quotes around something is called scare quotes. They are only used when:

a) the term is being used in a non-standard way
b) to mark off irony

I assume that you are not using "bar" in an ironic context, so it boils down to a question: are you using "bar" in a non-standard way? For example, you wouldn't put quotes around the following:

*DNA is sometimes divided into nucleotides.*

You would use quotes if you said:

*DNA is sometimes divided into "letters."*

Because "letter" is a non-standard term in the context of DNA, it needs scare quotes.

---

> Note

If you are trying to emphasize a word/phrase, *never use quotes*! Use italics instead.

Comment: Is it still scare quotes when saying "what is called" beforehand?  The OP is saying what someone called it,  reporting what someone was said.  While I agree with your analysis about the usage of scare quotes in general, I'm not convinced that's what would be happening here.  Rather, I think any use of quotation marks here would be their traditional usage for indicating what someone said, or in this case, someone "called."

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is to foo, producing what is called a "bar".
>
> The solution is to foo, producing what is called a *bar*.

[According to *Three Editors Blog* - last rule in the article](https://theeditorsblog.net/2014/05/12/marking-text-choosing-between-italics-and-quotation-marks/): You can use *either* quotes or italics. I would classify the quoted word here *words as words*. We often use italics for words used as words, but we can also use quotation marks.

Additionally, [according to APA Style Blog - paragraph 2](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/04/using-italics-for-technical-or-key-terms.html): The APA Manual (on p. 105) recommends using italics for the “introduction of a new, technical, or key term or label," adding "(after a term has been used once, do not italicize it).”

Thus, it seems that both may be acceptable but lean toward *italics*.

Answer (score 0):

You would use [quotation marks](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/quotation.htm). You're reporting what it is "called." When you borrow a word or phrase from someone else as I just did from you, then that is precisely what quotation marks are for.